# ¿Como heredar el constructor en herencia multiple de una super-clase secundaria en python3?

Tags: python-3.x, herencia

### ¿Como heredar el constructor en herencia multiple de una super-clase secundaria en python3?

Saludos Tengo una duda, como puedo hacer que la sub-clase: "MiClase" herede el constructor de la super-clase "MiSuperClase2" en herencia multiple??

> Codigo | Python3:

```
class MiSuperClase1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        self.b = "b"

    def metodo_1(self):
        print("metodo_1 metodo llamado")

class MiSuperClase2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = "c"
        self.d = "d"

    def metodo_2(self):
        print("metodo_2 metodo llamado")

class MiClase(MiSuperClase1, MiSuperClase2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def metodo_3(self):
        print("metodo_3 metodo llamado")
        #print(self.c, self.d)

c = MiClase()
c.metodo_3()
```

> Dudas:

Tengo unas dudas, gracias por responderlas:

¿Como se denomina de manera correcta la super-clase "MiSuperClase2" cuando es la clase padre de "MiClase" pero es secundaria(por asi decirlo)?

se denomina: super-clase 2, super-clase secundaria?(Nose si me hago entender...)

**De Antemano Muchas Gracias Por Sus Respuestas!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas `super()`, obtienes una referencia a la primera clase base en el caso de que heredes de varias.

Si quieres que `super()` se refiera a `MiSuperClase2` basta que cambies el orden en que declaras la herencia:

```
class MiClase(MiSuperClase2, MiSuperClase1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

En este caso el constructor llamará al de `MiSuperClase2`.

En caso de que quieras acceder a ambos constructores, por ejemplo para llamarlos en secuencia, `super()` no es de ayuda. Pero siempre puedes usar directamente los nombres de las clases:

```
class MiClase(MiSuperClase2, MiSuperClase1):
    def __init__(self):
        MiSuperClase2.__init__()
        MiSuperClase1.__init__()
```

El único problema de esto es que si alguna vez cambias la jerarquía de clases, y `MiClase` deja de heredar de estas dos, tienes que recordar modificar su `__init__()`.

Si quieres hacerlo más automático (pero cada vez menos legible):

```
class MiClase(MiSuperClase2, MiSuperClase1):
    def __init__(self):
        for clase in self.__class__.__bases__:
            clase.__init__()
```

El orden en que salen listadas en `__bases__` es el que hayas puesto entre paréntesis en la declaración de `MiClase`

Que yo sepa no hay ningún nombre especial para qué clase es la "principal" y cual la "secundaria", ya que realmente no veo por qué una clase base ha de ser más secundaria que otra, especialmente cuando la jerarquía de clases se enreda y tienes herencia múltiple de varias, que heredan a su vez de otra (quizás común), etc. En un diagrama de clases UML no se marca gráficamente de forma especial la "principal".

Al final lo que importa es saber en qué orden va a buscar python en esa jerarquía de clases cuando tenga que resolver un atributo como `self.algo`, si el objeto no lo tiene. Si quieres conocer ese orden, puedes hacer `Clase.mro()` para obtener la lista de todas las clases de las que `Clase` hereda, directa o indirectamente, y en el orden en que python las consultará para resolver un atributo o método.

Comment: Gracias por la info y por responder!!

Comment: Excelente explicación, gracias!