# Llenar constructores en multiple herencia python

Tags: python, poo, herencia, constructor

Estoy aprendiendo `python` y me ha surgido la siguiente duda: ¿Cómo puedo pasar los argumentos a los constructores de las clases padre desde una clase hijo que recibe múltiple herencia?

Clase Vehiculo:

```
class Vehiculo():
    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo 
        self.enmarcha = False
        self.acelera = False
        self.frena = False

    def arrancar(self):
        self.enmarcha = True

    def acelerar(self):
        self.acelera = True

    def frenar(self):
        self.frena = True

    def estado(self):
        print("\n Marca:", self.marca, "\n","Modelo:", self.modelo,"\n","En marcha:",self.enmarcha,"\n","Acelera:",
              self.acelera,"\n","Frena:",self.frena)
```

Clase Vehiculo Electrico:

```
class VElectrico():
    def __init__(self):
        self.autonomia = 100

    def cargarEnergia(self):
        self.cargando = True
```

Clase BicicletaElectrica:

```
class BicicletaElectrica(VElectrico, Vehiculo):
    pass
```

Instancia del objeto

```
miBici = BicicletaElectrica()
```

En este caso quiero llamar al método `estado()` que hereda de la clase `Vehiculo`, pero no se puede utilizar ya que la clase nunca recibe los argumentos del constructor.

Normalmente si fuera una herencia simple podriamos utilizar:

```
super().__init__(argumentos)
```

pero no es el caso, he intentado con lo siguiente pero no logro entender como pasar los argumentos especificando para que clase son:

```
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("marca","modelo")
        # Vehiculo.__init__(self,"bicicleta","mc2000")
        # super(Vehiculo).__init__(self,"bicicleta","mc2000")
```

¿Cual seria la forma de correcta de poder pasar los argumentos a la clase Vehiculo?

Comment: Posible duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227064/como-heredar-el-constructor-en-herencia-multiple-de-una-super-clase-secundaria

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como heredar el constructor en herencia multiple de una super-clase secundaria en python3?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227064/como-heredar-el-constructor-en-herencia-multiple-de-una-super-clase-secundaria)